# Laravel 5.2 application migrating from mysql to mongodb, but Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel-5

I am migrating my application from mysql to mongodb but some of the queries not working in mongodb:

```
$data = Post::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H')""),Carbon::createFromTimestamp(time(),'America/New_York')->format('Y-m-d H'))->count(\DB::raw('DISTINCT postName'));
```

Here, i don' t know how to write this query for mongodb. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel database does not support mongodb. It supports four databases: MySQL, Postgres, SQLite and SQL Server.

If you want to use mongodb in php, this will be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

or find third-party mongodb driver in https://packagist.org/

Comment: I know that, i have installed drivers, if you see i have mentioned some of the query not working. as above query. I am looking to convert the above query into mongodb.